# label with display:inline-block starts from next line

Tags: html, css

As we know display: inline and display:inline-block give same results when particular CSS properties (padding, width, margin etc..) are not defined

so if I use only display: inline-block on label element It should give me similar results as it gives me with display: inline

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h"><label style="display:inline-block;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
<div>

<br>
<br>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h"><label style="display:inline;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
<div>
```

But as you can see in snippet if I use "display: inline-block" label element starts from a new line,

Could someone explain the reason behind that?

Comment: You forgot something important which is the *block* part in the inline-block, so yes it behaves like inline but has some block property also thus the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't set width for `inline-block` element,it get width equal width of content.

If the width of the content is greater than the space left, then it goes to the next line Otherwise it will stay on the same line with `checkbox`

**Try This:**

```
div:first-child label {
  width: 90%;
  vertical-align: top; <-------For align `label` and `checkbox`
}
```

```css
div:first-child label {
  width: 90%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label class="x" style="display:inline-block;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo
  </label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label style="display:inline;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that text is sooo long. So when the text is longer, it will automatically wrap and break into the next line.

Find the example below and check if it is what you were expecting as a result.

Here I am using `flexbox`, so in case if you have browser support like IE11 and below, have to use an alternative method.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  
}
label {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label style="display:inline-block;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label style="display:inline;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
</div>
```

In case of IE11, you will need to give width as static value and need to modify it for each resolutions using media queries.

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20px;
}
label {
  float: right;
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label style="display:inline-block;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">
  <label style="display:inline;">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this also runs in IE11

Answer (score -1):

display inline block makes the divs appear in line but 
 is used to make something appear on new line, remove the br from your code,place those two divs inside another div & give display inline block to the parent div.if its still not working give a width of 50% to first and 50% to second div

Answer (score -1):

You can always try

```
<label><input> My text</label>
```

For example:

```html
<div><label style="display:inline-block;">
<input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
<div>

<br>
<br>

<div><label style="display:inline;">
<input type="checkbox" value=1 name ="h">rekjhnfkjjjjjjjjjgr fnerkjgkjnkreger gherheru hgir ghoerg oerjg oejrg oerjg oejg ooijer gioerug jerg oerjg eoguj oejg orejg oire ghor tor tgjoirj goih roghori hgorhgo iherog horeh goer ghoeri ghoierh goiehr ge roigh oerig oierg oeh goie gioerh goir oigh rioh goirhgioh roighoir hfgoihroigh oirthfiog hoifhgoirhtiog iohgoihroi ghoirh goid hgioh rioghiofh goihfoihg iohfiogh roidhgoirh oig riohgoirh gohrioh goihftioghfo</label>
<div>
```